# java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2017' is not a leap year Java

Tags: java, date, jcombobox, localdate

I am try to get starting and ending date in Java, i Have List of Month from January to December in `JCombobox` and Year  `JCombobox` to Dispay Years.

First i have converted `String` month to month number and using this Code:

```
if(month_sands.getSelectedIndex() != -1){
        int monthnumber = month_sands.getSelectedIndex() + 1;

         if(monthnumber>=9)
         {
             month=String.valueOf(monthnumber);

         }else
         {
             month="0"+String.valueOf(monthnumber);
         }

    }
```

Then Later i have Created a String `dateString` to get the First and Last date of the Selected month using `LocalDate`, every thing is working fine but when i select February month and Year 2017 it give me Exception `java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'February 29' as '2017' is not a leap year`

The code to Get the first and last date is

```
try {
        String dateString = year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+month+"-"+"01";   
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US); 
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);
        LocalDate startDate=date.withDayOfMonth(1);
        LocalDate endDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().maxLength());

        start_date=startDate.toString();
        end_date=endDate.toString();

        System.out.println(start_date);
        System.out.println(end_date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I dont know what am doing wrong please some one help me

Comment: i know that but how the exception is getting raised can you explain

Comment: By the way, in the future, please include the full stack trace of the exception -- and/or add a comment into your code explaining which line the exception happened on.

Comment: Ok and i got my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It happens because you are using `maxLength()` in this line:

```
LocalDate endDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().maxLength());
```

The method `maxLength()` returns the maximum length of this month in days, as the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#maxLength--) says. The month February indeed has a maximum of 29 days (just not in 2017, but this is about the month February in general, not in any particular year!).

This should work, because it takes the length of the month in the specific year into account:

```
LocalDate endDate = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());
```

Comment: Please answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129200/resolverstyle-strict-is-not-working-in-datetimeformatiso-datetimeformat-iso

Answer (score 3):

The method [maxLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#maxLength--) is not suitable to determine the context-dependent length of February (either 28 or 29 days). That method always yields 29.

You should consider the method [lengthOfMonth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#lengthOfMonth--) instead.

Comment: That Helped Meno Hochschild +1 Thanks a lot

Comment: PLease answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129200/resolverstyle-strict-is-not-working-in-datetimeformatiso-datetimeformat-iso

Answer (score 1):

```
        String dateString = year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+month+"-"+"01"; 

        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormat);
        LocalDate startDate = date.withDayOfMonth(1);
        LocalDate endDate = null;
        if (Integer.parseInt(month) == 02) {
            if (isLeapYear(Integer.parseInt(year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString()))) {
                endDate = LocalDate.parse(year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-02" + "-29", dateFormat);
            }
            else
            {
                endDate = LocalDate.parse(year_sands.getSelectedItem().toString() + "-02" + "-28", dateFormat);
            }
        } else {
             endDate= date.withDayOfMonth(date.getMonth().maxLength());

        }


public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Try above code.
Hope this will helps you.