# ResolverStyle.STRICT is not working in `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`

Tags: java, spring, validation, date, datetime

I am using:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonFormat( pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy" )
private LocalDate start;
```

but it accept `02-30-2019` and convert to `02-28-2019` Automatically. But i want restrict that date.

I also used:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
@JsonFormat( pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy" )
private LocalDate start;
```

but it give compile time error: `Attribute value must be constant`.

ankit here:

I have same issue and also used `u` in place of `y` but not help:

```
@FutureOrPresent
@DateTimeFormat( iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE,pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu")
@JsonFormat( pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu" )
private LocalDate start;
```

i want to restrict at time of parsing. It accept `02-31-2019` and convert automatically to `02-28-2019`. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104034/6097074

Now **09/08/2018**

If i am using:
    private LocalDate start;//without using DateTimeFormat and JsonFormat annotation

this work fine if i use: `yyyy-MM-dd` format date in json i.e. `2014-01-01`. 
But i need to parse to `MM-dd-yyyy`.

Kind help to solve this,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share some code or even try to make your question a bit more understandable?

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Please view question again. i editted

Comment: @ankit An invalid date (like 2019-02-30) cannot be parsed with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`. Maybe your problem is rather in the JSON-layer.

Comment: @MenoHochschild you are right, An invalid date (like 2019-02-30) cannot be parsed with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`. But i am not able to use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`. Please read question carefully. Thanks

Comment: @ankit Are you using Joda-Time instead when specifying the annotation `@DateTimeFormat`? That is not the same.

Comment: No we are not using joda in any case.

Comment: @MenoHochschild please reply?

Comment: @ankit Hm, looking at the [spring source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8aa6e5bfea2c7314deaa1b432554e9e914b09ee7/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeFormatterFactory.java#L180) does not seem to support your statement that Spring uses a non-strict parser, but I am not in the position to test it.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Please check this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.java

Comment: @ankit I can't understand it. Please help

Comment: @MenoHochschild yes as per your link springframwork code ude ristrict but !!. Please refer abhinay link if you understand this. Thanks

Comment: @ankit I have read the link and can only say: Verify that Spring 4 and Java 8+ are used.That means check if JSR-310 (=java.time-API) is really used under the hood (configuration issue?). Another question is: Which annotation will be used if setting the value of field "start"? If it is not DateTimeFormat but JSonFormat then the JSonFormat might use a non-strict parser. Have you checked it (for example by leaving out the annotation for JSon)?

Comment: @MenoHochschild i am using Spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE and yes i also think that this is problem by `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.@JsonFormat` annotation. But without using it i am getting `Parsing error: cannot Deserialize`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild yes JSR-310 is used

Comment: @MenoHochschild Please check edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got solution for your problem:

**remove below line**

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
@JsonFormat( pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy" )
```

and just use:

```
private LocalDate start;
```

and send date in **yyyy-MM-dd** or **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss** (default date format for Date parsing in spring with ResolverStyle.Strict) date format.

Comment: @AKA Please tell me what if i want to use "MM-dd-yyyy" format?

Comment: @ankit No you can't use this format with ResolverStyle.Strict.